# Puppeteer: How do I get the value from the loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

I need to load the code on the page that will check the value of one element in a loop and after it becomes necessary, then return this value.
How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague, so I'm note sure if I understood correctly, but you may be looking for page.evaluate(). With this function you can execute code on browser context and then return some information.

Ex.:

```
var output = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let urlSelector= '#someId > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a';
        let desiredUrl = document.querySelector(urlSelector).href;
        console.log(desiredUrl);//print the url in browser console
        return desiredUrl;
});
console.log(output);//prints the url in node console
```

In this example I executed the code in browser context and returned a desired url to the "output" variable in my script.